# Error with Selectionsort

Tags: java, sorting

I've tried many different variations, and I keep getting the same problem. After selectio nsort runs, the number of items outputted, does not match the size of my array. I've been running through with any array of size 10, yet the output does not contain 10 numbers. However, the output of selection sort is sorted.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class Sorts {

public static Integer[] createArray(int size) {
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        list.add(i);
    Collections.shuffle(list);
    Integer[] array = list.toArray(new Integer[list.size()]);
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(array[i]);
    }
    return array;

}

public static void selectionSort(Integer[] array) {
    Integer min;
    for (Integer i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
        min = i;
        for (Integer j = i + 1; j < array.length; j++) {
            if (array[j].compareTo(array[min]) > 0) {
                min = j;
            }
        }
        if (min != i) {
            Integer temp = array[i];
            array[i] = array[min];
            array[min] = temp;
            System.out.print(array[i]);

        }

    }
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    int number = 10;
    Integer[] list = createArray(number);
    System.out.println("");
    selectionSort(list);

}
```

}

Comment: you could try Collections.sort(Arrays.asList(array));

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you make a swap, you print out a number. But in an array of 10 elements, you'll only make 9 swaps -- the final element will already be in its correct place! To fix this, add `System.out.print(array[array.length - 1]);` to the end of your function.

Also, if the minimum element happens to be `i`, then no swap will be performed and no element printed. This still sorts the array, but if you want it to be printed out, you could remove the `if (min != i)` statement and simply do a swap on every pass through the list.

You should also take a look at using `int`s rather than `Integer`s. An `Integer` is generally slower than an `int` and you usually only use them when Java wants an object.